# CSS Issue: Hidden children stretching along Y-axis in IE with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've been able to do this in Chrome and Firefox, and I thought I had it working in IE7 and IE8, but alas, I must've been dreaming.

Basically I have the following HTML:

```
<style>
div,li,ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
}
ul,li {  
    list-style: none;
}
div#container {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 600px;
   height: 120px;
   border: 1px solid lime;
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
}
div#container > ul {
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
div#container > ul > li {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
   <ul>
      <li>Item 0</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And I want it to look like this:

(from Firefox)
[image: Firefox Example]

(from Chrome)
[image: Chrome Example]

instead it looks like this:

(from IE8)
[image]

I'm at my wits end with this, and I'm considering doing some table layout hackery to fix it. But I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

Comment: Check you cache in IE. Sometimes it can send you mad when you are developing and making changes to CSS and JS and it simply does not respond in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it... stupid IE incompatibilities. Basically it didn't like my selectors. So I had to add a class to the ul tag and do things that way.

```
<style>
div,li,ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
}
ul,li {  
    list-style: none;
}
div#container {
   display: inline;
   width: 600px;
   height: 120px;
   border: 1px solid lime;
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
}
div#container ul.first {
   display: inline;
   width: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
div#container ul.first li {
   display: inline;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
   <ul class="first">
      <li>Item 0</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```